# Yii2 render html content in custom validation rule addError method

Tags: model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have defined the custom validation rule:

```
['Email', 'checkUniqueExistence'],

public function checkUniqueExistence($attribute, $params)
{
        $email = $this->$attribute;

        $checkUniqueExistenceForEmail = Parents::find()->where([ 'Email' =>  $email])->One();

        $resendActivationLink = Html::a('Resend Link','#');

        if(count($checkUniqueExistenceForEmail) > 0){
            if($checkUniqueExistenceForEmail->IsAccountActivated == Yii::$app->params['IsAccountActivatedTrue']){
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Email address already exists');
            }
            else{
                $this->addError($attribute, 'You haven\'t activated your account. Request '.$resendActivationLink);
            }
        }

}
```

But link does not generate. It is displayed as a string. I got the following output after submitting the form:

```
You haven't activated your account. Request <a href="#">Resend Link</a>
```

Is it possible to display link in addError() method?

Comment: A more effective method will be to display the Resend Link conditionally based on whether the error object is set or not ..

Comment: eg : if($this->hasError) { show_link } else { hide_link } , you can add something like this in your view

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. But still the question arises why does the addError method does not render HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass this configuration array to ActiveField

```
'errorOptions' => ['encode' => false]
```